# Segmentation fault with MPI_Comm_Rank

Tags: c++, makefile, mpi

I have to work on a code written a few years ago which uses MPI and PETSc.
When I try to run it, I have an error with the function MPI_Comm_rank().
Here is the beginning of the code :

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    double mesure_tps2,mesure_tps1;
    struct timeval tv;
    time_t curtime2,curtime1;
    
    char help[] = "Solves linear system with KSP.\n\n";  // NB: Petsc est defini dans "fafemo_Constant_Globales.h"


    std::cout<< "d�but PetscInitialize" <<std::endl;
    (void*) PetscInitialize(&argc,&argv,(char *)0,help);
    std::cout<< "d�but PetscInitialize fait" <<std::endl;

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    PetscFinalize();

}
```

Obviously, there are some code between MPI_Comm_rank() and PetscFinalize().
PetscInitialize and PetscFinalize call respectively MPI_INIT and MPI_FINALIZE.

In my makefil I have :

```
PETSC_DIR=/home/thib/Documents/bibliotheques/petsc-3.13.2
PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux-c-debug
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/conf/rules

PETSC36 = -I/home/thib/Documents/bibliotheques/petsc-3.13.2/include -I/home/thib/Documents/bibliotheques/petsc-3.13.2/arch-linux-c-debug/include

Mpi_include=-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi

#a variable with some files names
fafemo_files = fafemo_CI_CL-def.cc fafemo_Flux.cc fafemo_initialisation_probleme.cc fafemo_FEM_setup.cc fafemo_sorties.cc fafemo_richards_solve.cc element_read_split.cpp point_read_split.cpp read_split_mesh.cpp


PETSC_KSP_LIB_VSOIL=-L/home/thib/Documents/bibliotheques/petsc-3.13.2/  -lpetsc_real -lmpi -lmpi++

fafemo:    ${fafemo_files} fafemo_Richards_Main.o
    g++ ${CXXFLAGS} -g -o fafemo_CD ${fafemo_files} fafemo_Richards_Main.cc ${PETSC_KSP_LIB_VSOIL} $(PETSC36) ${Mpi_include}
```

Using g++ or mpic++ doesn't seem to change anything.

It compiles, but when I try to execute I have :

```
[thib-X540UP:03696] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[thib-X540UP:03696] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[thib-X540UP:03696] Failing at address: 0x44000098
[thib-X540UP:03696] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3efd0)[0x7fbfa87e4fd0]
[thib-X540UP:03696] [ 1] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.20(MPI_Comm_rank+0x42)[0x7fbfa9533c42]
[thib-X540UP:03696] [ 2] ./fafemo_CD(+0x230c8)[0x561caa6920c8]
[thib-X540UP:03696] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7fbfa87c7b97]
[thib-X540UP:03696] [ 4] ./fafemo_CD(+0x346a)[0x561caa67246a]
[thib-X540UP:03696] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node thib-X540UP exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, I have others MPI programs on my computer and I never had such a problem.
Does anyone know why do I get this ?

Comment: you might be mixing Open MPI include files (in your `Makefile`) and the mpich based library used by petsc. try running `ldd` on your petsc library to double check which MPI implementation is used internally.

Comment: Ok I see. But I don't understand "try running ```ldd``` on your petsc library". Sorry, I'm really new to petsc and have to use codes using it. Also I tried to give to path to the file mpi.h that is in the petsc folders to make sure that the ```#include "mpi.h"``` are done with that file. It still doesn't work

Comment: does your code still crash if you comment out the `MPI_Comm_rank()` call?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet it crashes later because one need the variable world_rank

Comment: Also I changed the PetscInitialize() and PetscFinalize() to use MPI_INIT() and MPI_FINALIZE. I still have the error

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same issue :
When I installed PETSc, I ran ./configure with --download-mpich while I already had mpi installed on my computer.
To solve the problem I did "rm -rf ${PETSC_ARCH}" and ran ./configure again.